# How do I access certain info from a JSON data file? is it through array form?

Tags: javascript, json

In the following JSON data, I want to access `'lon'` and `'lat'` in `'coord'`. I know `data.coord` would give me `[ 'lon', 'lat' ]`, but how can I get the values belonging to each?

Here's my JSON data:

```
var data = {
    "coord": {
        "lon": 159,
        "lat": 35
    },
    ...
};
```

Comment: yea using javascript

Comment: `console.log(data.coord.lon,data.coord.lat)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accesss them like this:

```js
var data = { "coord":{ "lon":159, "lat":35 }, "weather":[ { "id":500, "main":"Rain", "description":"light rain", "icon":"https://cdn.glitch.com/6e8889e5-7a72-48f0-a061-863548450de5%2F10n.png?1499366021399" } ], "base":"stations", "main":{ "temp":22.59, "pressure":1027.45, "humidity":100, "temp_min":22.59, "temp_max":22.59, "sea_level":1027.47, "grnd_level":1027.45 }, "wind":{ "speed":8.12, "deg":246.503 }, "rain":{ "3h":0.45 }, "clouds":{ "all":92 }, "dt":1499521932, "sys":{ "message":0.0034, "sunrise":1499451436, "sunset":1499503246 }, "id":0, "name":"", "cod":200 };

console.log('Lon',data.coord.lon);
console.log('Lat',data.coord.lat);

//Also you can do that using object destructuring in es6 like this:

var {lon,lat} = data.coord;
console.log('Lon',lon);
console.log('Lat',lat);
```

Checkout MDN for more about objects and properties:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Check out [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: How do i access the weather object? because if i do data.weather it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: data.weather works fine just tested.It returns an array with a single element.To access this object you can write data.weather[0]

Answer (score 1):

`data.coord` won't give you `[ 'lon', 'lat' ]` array, rather it would give you `{ "lon": 159,"lat": 35 }` object.

You can get their values just like you would get value of any object like: `data.coord.lat` and `data.coord.lon`

So something like 

`var latitude = data.coord.lat; 
var longitude = data.coord.lon`

**EDIT:**

Similarly, for weather you can access weather using `data.weather`, however thing to note is that weather is an array. So, you can get hold of 1st element using index=0.

Effectively, you'll write, `var myWeatherObject = data.weather[0];` //0 is index of 1st element

Again, to access individual weather properties, you can use:
`myWeatherObject.id`, `myWeatherObject.main`, `myWeatherObject.description` and `myWeatherObject.icon`

Comment: what about weather? how do i access that?

Comment: JSON provided in question doesn't has any `weather` key, so I'm assuming it'll be present. You can access weather the same way you access any key in JSON. e.g `data.weather`. Post full JSON for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the values with this syntax `data['coord']`.
With this syntax you can run through the json file searching for a corresponding key.

```
for(let key in json) {
 if(key==='coord'){
//do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the reason of looping through object properties instead of direct accessing them?